# Fetch all children of parents in Core Data using predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, relationships

I have a data model relationship of Person - Children in Core Data.
So for example, A Person can have children and his children can have children, and so his children's children can have children and so on.

How would I be able to fetch all the children, grand children and grand grand children using a predicate?

Comment: Can a child have only one parent, or more than one?

Comment: Child can only have 1 parent.

Comment: And are `Child` and `Person` different entities?  Or is `children` a reflexive relationship from `Person` to `Person`?

Comment: @pbasdf They are just the same entity and is reflexive.

Comment: @LittleTinyDev did you got solution for this ?

Comment: @ParagBafna Unfortunately I did not find an easy way to do this using a predicate. But you have to go thru or scan your objects for children to get them.

Comment: I have decided to use parent child relationship to avoid looping.  But it's not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837975/folder-structure-in-core-data

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Person object, `thePerson`, then to fetch their children you would use the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format:"parent == %@", thePerson)
```

To fetch their grandchildren, use:

```
NSPredicate(format:"parent.parent == %@", thePerson)
```

and for their great-grandchildren, use:

```
NSPredicate(format:"parent.parent.parent == %@", thePerson)
```

Combine those together:

```
NSPredicate(format:"parent == %@ OR parent.parent == %@ OR parent.parent.parent == %@", thePerson, thePerson, thePerson)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And pardon me if I used a "fixed" example in my question. But what if I do not know the number of levels to get the outmost children.

Comment: I was afraid you might want that.  I think you might need to change your model - but I will have to think through how best to change it.